# Passing a modified file content to a command that need the file path

Tags: python, subprocess

Consider I have a command that take as input a path of a file and compiles this file.
I want call this command from a **python** script using **subprocess**.

With python I have extract the file content and modified it, that I want to compile.
I do not need to store the new file content I want to compile.

The question is:

Is there a way (a method in subprocess for example) to compile the file content without manually writing and then removing in the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

You can give your compile/run command in the syntax.

Further, supply the executable/filename with full path.

```
P = subprocess.Popen(['your_run_command','filename_with_path', 'any_extra_parameter_you_want_to_add'], STDIN=subprocess.PIPE,STDOUT=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output,err = P.communicate()
P.wait()

#For removing the already existing file
if os.path.exists('filename_with_path'):
    os.remove('filename_with_path')
```

Comment: Thanks...so in this case you need to write in explicitly in the filesystem. if `f` is my file `f.write(filename)`

Comment: No just write your filename in the string format in the subprocess.Popen args.For example subprocess.Popen(['python','/home/myuser/directory/myfile.py'],...above parameters..) will run your python script myfile.py and capture the output/error using stdout/stderr

Comment: A file generated by anything will always have a location where it is stored/indexed after generation. To get file location there is a command 'find' in unix. Any unix command can be called through python using os.system()

Comment: Sorry I express my self baddly...what I intended is that I got the file content then I modified the file content with a python script, and now I want use this content without write it in the file and call the filepath for the command.

Comment: @vigte In that case you can use os.touch() to create a temp file in some location and then you can run that file according to your needs and remove it using os.remove(). Further, if you really don't want to write to some file then you will have to clarify your situation in some more narrower detail